# Find subdomain using domain instances in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, orm

In grails, how do I find subdomain using domain instances

Let say I have

```
class Family {
    Integer id
    Parent parent
}


class Parent {
    Interger id
    static hasMany = [children: Child]
}

class Child {
    String name
}
```

So in controller,

```
Parent mom = Family.findById(1).parent
```

so now, how do I use `mom` to get a child with `name == "Child"` in parent?
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work.

```
Child child = mom.children.find { it.name == 'child' }
```

But I do not recommend using this kind of queries. Grails has many ways for querying you can read about it here http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#querying. I also recommend to you this guide http://guides.grails.org/querying-gorm-dynamic-finders/guide/index.html its about dynamic finders in contrast to queries that use groovy collection methods for querying.

I hope its help full

Comment: This worked for me in this specific situation but I will keep in mind about those documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [criteria API](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) for that:

```
Parent.withCriteria {
    children {
        eq("name", "Bob")
    }
}
```

In this example `children` will be joined to the `parent`. And all parents will be returned, that have a child called "Bob".

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use closure findAll{} this way:

```
  def childrenList=mom.findAll{it.children.each{
                   if(it.name=='child')
                      return it
                     }
                    }
```

This will give you a list of all the children objects with name 'Child'.

Answer (score 0):

As @user615274 has suggested, the accepted solution works but that it may have performance issues.

One feature that Grails shine is the dynamic query. I would modify the Child domain and use dynamic query. eg.

Since Parent "hasMany" relation to Child, the child "belongsTo" the Parent

```
class Child {
    String name

    Parent parent  
    // or static belongsTo = [parent:Parent] 
}
```

Once this relationship is setup, then you can use dynamic query

```
def child = Child.findByParent(mom)   // return the first matching result
def children = Child.findAllByParent(mom)  // returns a list of matching result
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I understand that belongs will work too but in this particular case I need a method to extract information without changing the domain, Thanks.